# Instruction set simulator written in Python fails

Tags: python, function, memory, assembly, printing

This is my instruction set simulator Python script:

```
MEM_SIZE=100;

reg={'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0, 'd':0, 'e':0,'f':0,'sp':0,'acc':0, 'pc':0, 'ivec':0, 'int':0, 'timer':0, 'halt':False};

memory=[0]*MEM_SIZE;

def mov(opr):
    reg[opr[0]]=reg[opr[1]];
    reg['pc']=reg['pc']+1;

def movv(opr):
    reg[opr[0]]=int(opr[1]);
    reg['pc']=reg['pc']+1;

def load(opr):
    reg[opr[0]]=memory[int(opr[1])];
    reg['pc']=reg['pc']+1;

def loadr(opr):
    reg[opr[0]]=memory[reg[opr[1]]];
    reg['pc']=reg['pc']+1;


def add(opr):
    reg['acc']=reg[opr[0]]+reg[opr[1]];
    reg['pc']=reg['pc']+1;

def sub(opr):
    reg['acc']=reg[opr[0]]-reg[opr[1]];
    reg['pc']=reg['pc']+1;


def call(opr):
    reg['sp']=reg['sp']+1;
    memory[reg['sp']]=reg['pc']+1;
    reg['pc']=int(opr[0]);


def out(opr):
    print reg[opr[0]];
    reg['pc']=reg['pc']+1;

def push(opr):
    reg['sp']=reg['sp']+1;
    memory[reg['sp']]=reg[opr[0]];
    reg['pc']=reg['pc']+1;

def pop(opr):
    reg[opr[0]]=memory[reg['sp']];
    reg['sp']=reg['sp']-1;
    reg['pc']=reg['pc']+1;


def halt(opr):
    reg['halt']=True;
    reg['pc']=reg['pc']+1;


f=open('ass-2.asm','r');

def runm():
    while reg['halt']==False:
        i=reg['pc'];
        op=globals()[memory[i][0]];
        #print i,memory[i][0:] ;
        op(memory[i][1:]);
        pass;

        reg['timer']=reg['timer']-1;
        if reg['int']==1 and reg['timer']==0:
            reg['sp']=reg['sp']+1;
            memory[reg['sp']]=reg['pc'];
            reg['pc']=reg['ivec'];
            reg['int']=0;



for l in f:
    if l.startswith("#"):
        continue;

    comm= l.split();
    if comm:
        memory[int(comm[0])] = comm[1:];

runm();

print reg;
print memory;
```

The file `ass-2.asm` contains the assembly language instructions to run:

```
0 movv sp 80
1 movv a 100
2 movv b 400
3 call 20
4 add a b
5 out acc
6 halt

20 push a
21 push b
22 push acc
23 movv a 20
24 movv b 80
25 add a b
26 out acc
27 pop acc
28 pop b
29 pop a
30 ret
```

The output I expect is:

```
100
500
```

The output and error I receive is:

```
100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sim.py", line 86, in <module>
    runm();
  File "sim.py", line 64, in runm
    op=globals()[memory[i][0]];
KeyError: 'ret'
```

The problem appears to be in the `runm` function.

I think 2 numbers should be loaded to a register before the function is called and they should be added  after the function call! The value of the memory printed should be 500 but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Where do you handle `ret`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your virtual machine misses a function that handles the `ret` command. Something like this should work:

```py
def ret(opr):
    reg['pc'] = memory[reg['sp']]
    reg['sp'] = reg['sp'] - 1
```

Comment: Don't you also want to adjust SP?

Comment: I think ``sp`` is already increased in the ``call`` function.

Comment: Yes, but what do you think `ret` should do? Imagine if you had nested calls. `ret` needs to adjust the _SP_ in the opposite direction that a `call` did to effectively pop the return address off.Merely setting _PC_ to what was on the top of the stack doesn't pop that return address off.

Comment: @Michael Petch: True, absolutely true. I changed the method accordingly.